# Secure user authentication on PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage user authentication.

At the moment I'm using this way

```
include("Conection.php");
$usuario = $_POST["Nick"];
$contra = $_POST["Pass"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nick = '$usuario' AND Password = '$contra'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($result->num_rows == 0) { 
      echo '<script languaje=javacript>
    alert ("Inicion de sesion rechazada")
    window.location="../Entrar.html"
    </script>';
} 
else 
{ 
     // Inicias la sesion 
     session_start(); 
     $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $row['Nick']; 
     $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Autenticado'; 
     echo ("<script>location.href='../../Index.php'</script>");
     // Muestras el contenido de la pagina 
}
```

and if my user logs in he will have different menu options

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['Usuario']) and $_SESSION['estado'] == 'Autenticado')                    { ?>
    <a href="Navegacion/Entrar.html">Logeado</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php } 
    else 
    {    ?>
    <a href="Navegacion/Entrar.html">Entrar</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Navegacion/Registrarse.html">Registrarse</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="Navegacion/Carrito.html"><img src="Images/Carrito.png" alt=""  width="20" height="20" ></a>
<?php   }    ?>
```

I know this way it's way weaker with SQL injections and stuff like that.

My main question was, Which it's the best way to protect againts sql injections, seems that the answer it's PDO, since I can not use comments and let me thank here all you that help me, thank you mdfst13

Comment: You already know that you have an SQL injection problem. Why don't you fix it instead of asking us to review code that you already know is problematic?

Comment: You also seem to be confusing the use of sessions with authentication/login state.  These are really two different things (though there are relations between the two when it comes to working with sessions securely). Also, why javascript redirections? Try looking at http://www.phptherightway.com/ to focus properly on the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Avoiding SQL injection

> ```
> $usuario = $_POST["Nick"];
> $contra = $_POST["Pass"]; 
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nick = '$usuario' AND Password = '$contra'";
> ```

The smallest change to this to avoid SQL injection would be something like

```
$usuario = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Nick']);
$contra = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Pass']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Nick = '$usuario' AND Password = '$contra'";
```

But modernly best practice is to use something like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with bind variables.  You don't include enough context to make that change here.

I also changed double quotes to single quotes because I prefer them for static strings.  I only use double quotes for interpolated strings like `$sql`.

#### PHP vs. Javascript

> ```
>       echo '<script languaje=javacript>
>     alert ("Inicion de sesion rechazada")
>     window.location="../Entrar.html"
>     </script>';
> ```

First, consider using a [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) for a multiline string.  E.g.

```
    echo <<<'EOSCRIPT'
<script languaje=javacript>
  alert ("Inicion de sesion rechazada")
  window.location="../Entrar.html"
</script>
EOSCRIPT;
```

But you generally don't want to do things like a redirect in Javascript.  Doing it with HTML [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/6660678) is more reliable.

```
    header('Location: ../Entrar.html');
```

Note that this should be an absolute URL, but I don't know which one.

You have to emit headers before any HTML, even the DOCTYPE.

Comment: I never needed an absolute URL in the header. Seemed to be working. (Chrome)